# java7 diamond operator convert compilation error

Tags: java, regex, java-7

I wanted to convert the current code to `Java7 diamond operator`.
I have the below regular expression for finding and replace.

Finding

```
new (\w+)<.+>
```

Replace:

```
new $1<>
```

The problem is it is
getting replaced for anonymous classes as well. Becuase of this I get compilation error.
So How do I write the regular expression which avoid inner classes?

Comment: Curios to know why do want to do this..   When you write new code, use new syntax. Leave the old code as it is.

Comment: The problem is that I have to convert all the existing code in to Java diamond operator. There are almost 10,000 occurences. So manually doing tedious.

Comment: Question is why? There is no performance gain, no real difference is readability..  regular expression may not work in all cases. Not sure if intelli's SSR could help.  or try http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : `(?s)new (\w+)<.+>(\(.*?\);)`

```
String test = "List<String> t = new ArrayList<String>();";
System.out.println(test.replaceAll("(?s)new (\\w+)<.+>(\\(.*?\\);)", "new $1<>$2"));

String test2 = "List<String> t = new ArrayList<String>(getList());";
System.out.println(test2.replaceAll("(?s)new (\\w+)<.+>(\\(.*?\\);)", "new $1<>$2"));

String test3 = "List<String> t = new ArrayList<String>(\n\tgetList(\n\t\tanotherMethod()\n\t)\n);";
System.out.println(test3.replaceAll("(?s)new (\\w+)<.+>(\\(.*?\\);)", "new $1<>$2"));

String test4 = "List<String> t = new List<String>(){ /* implementation */ };";
System.out.println(test4.replaceAll("(?s)new (\\w+)<.+>(\\(.*?\\);)", "new $1<>$2"));

String test5 = "List<String> t = new List<String>()\n{\n\t/* implementation */\n};";
System.out.println(test5.replaceAll("(?s)new (\\w+)<.+>(\\(.*?\\);)", "new $1<>$2"));
```

It prints :

```
List<String> t = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> t = new ArrayList<>(getList());
List<String> t = new ArrayList<>(
    getList(
        anotherMethod()
    )
);
List<String> t = new List<String>(){ /* implementation */ };
List<String> t = new List<String>()
{
    /* implementation */
};
```